# Proof of Stake how many blocks are proposed each round

Tags: proof-of-stake

So. I understand that the "nothing at stake" problem requires more than one chain being proposed. How can more than one chain be proposed? how many blocks are proposed each round? I thought that only one validator was supposed to win the selection and propose the block to be "forged". Please help me understand this.